# value is not appending in to div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am appending a html in to a div . But this is not working. please help me

```
<li>
  <a data-cke-saved-href="" href="" class="active" data-bookmark="1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor
  </a>
  <ul class="tab">
    <li>
      <p class="normal_p" style="">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia 
        architecto soluta maiores eos accusantium quos atque nihil? Facere, minus 
        eos cumque quasi dolor dolorum magnam quod non laborum placeat?
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li>
  <a data-cke-saved-href="" href="" class="active" data-bookmark="1">
    Lorem ipsum dolor
  </a>
  <ul class="tab">
    <li>
      <p class="normal_p" style="">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Facere officia
        architecto soluta maiores eos accusantium quos atque nihil? Facere, minus 
        eos cumque quasi dolor dolorum magnam quod non laborum placeat?
      </p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

i want append some html content in to a div. `attId`  will generate dynamically. That generate successfully. i only know `attId`. other elements are same so i can only use attr.

```
var attId = 1;
var anchor = document.querySelector('[data-bookmark="'+ attId +'"]');
$(anchor).children("ul li").html($(this).html());
```

Comment: what??? is this a complete question? How you get this `attId`? why `document.querySelector()`? instead of querySelector use `$()` jquery selector a more shorten way if jquery used.

Comment: What is attId in your code, where have you defined it?

Comment: `$(this).html()` here `$(this)` is not that what you think. The way you have asked this question its seems imposible to answer it. or if you could tell us what is `$(this).html()` is actually?

Comment: Please provide which content you want to append to which div. It is not clear from the question. Can you please edit your question a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appending a whole `html` to a `div` sound somehow and moreso why `querySelector()` in `jQuery`, the question is not clear, perhaps you post chunk of code that well describe what you mean

From what you posted

```
//assuming there is a var attId as 1

var attId = 1
var anchor =$('[data-bookmark="'+ attId +'"]'); 
$(anchor).children("ul li").html($(this).html());
```

Although what you are trying to insert into the list items is not clear, but I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

try this, because you're trying to get the children of the link and it does not have.

```
  var anchor = $('.normal_p').closest("li");
  anchor .html($(this).html());
```

or

```
  var anchor = $('.tab').children();
  anchor .html($(this).html());
```